# How do I create pagination links for my entry index page?

Tags: pagination

So I may be somewhat obtuse here, but I’m trying to discern what I might be doing wrong in this instance. I’m attempting to use a `{% paginate %}` tag inside my `craft.entries` loop to return a simple next/previous set of pagination links. I have ensured I have two entries already, so I should be seeing the pagination links, correct?

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('houseRules').limit(1) %}
    <div class="rule-content">
        <article>
            {# Content is Here #}
        </article>
    </div>
    {% paginate craft.entries as entries %}
        {% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
        {% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
    {% endpaginate %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is this meant to be on a single-entry page? And you just want to show Previous/Next links to the neighboring entries within this “House Rules” section?

Comment: No, sorry. I meant to say this was the index page. I just don’t have anything but a single entry on it at the moment, so I created a dummy entry to test against a limit of (1).

Comment: Got it, thanks. The `limit(1)` was throwing me off :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your `{% for %}` and `{% paginate %}` tags in the reverse order. You need to wrap the loop *and* the pagination URLs with the `{% paginate %}` tag pair:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('houseRules').limit(1) as entries %}

    {% for entry in entries %}
        <div class="rule-content">
            <article>
                {# Content is here #}
            </article>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
    {% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Notice how we’re actually looping through `entries`, rather than a new `craft.entries` call. That `entries` variable will be an array of the current page’s entries. All we had to do is define what we wanted that variable to be called (e.g. “entries”).

See http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags#paginate for more details on what can be done inside the `{% paginate %}` tag pair.

Comment: Great, thank you. That was tripping me up somewhat. I think it's because I'm still using an ExpressionEngine mentality when approaching pagination.